# MS Access back end located on slow network drive

Tags: ms-access

I currently have an Access 2003 app that is used primarialy by three people. It is split into a front end which each person has a copy of on their own machine and a back end on the server. When a user logs into the front end, the front end runs a start up routine that checks table links, version number and a few other things. The problem is that the shared drive is slow, very slow. It can take over a minute for the routine to finish up.

I tested it on another network that I know is faster. It took about 10 seconds to accomplish the same tasks. Unfortunately I don't have any choice on which network to put the app so it can be shared by the people who need to use it.  Does anyone have any suggestions as to what I can do on my end to speed things up? It seems to be more of a network issue than a problem with my design but my chances of getting help from our IT department are zero.

Comment: If your network connection is slow / the drive is slow, there is nothing you can do but to minimize impact from your start up routine. E.g. Check only one table and assume the others are existing. But besides minimizing the data to be transferred you cannot circumvent a slow network.

Comment: Thanks. That's pretty much what I figured but I wanted a second set of eyes to look at it so to speak. Appreciate the help

Comment: What kind of network is this? If it's WiFi or a WAN, then it's not an acceptable network for use with Jet/ACE databases.

Comment: The app was designed for our office LAN, however it had to be moved to the department newwork which is a WAN For what it is worth the network server is in the same the city. Due to office politics my options are/were using a Microsoft Office product (Access) or paper records.

Comment: A WAN is not going to work. It's going to be both slow and dangerous to the safety of your data. You should look into whether or not there's a Windows Terminal Server (or Citrix) available for you to host the app on.

Comment: If I had other options I would have used them. We're talking office politics here. I lost the battle.

Comment: Do they realize that by not providing you with other options, they are endangering their data? Do you fully understand the danger to the data of editing it across a WAN?

Comment: I'm well aware of the problems. Unforltunately the issue is being driven by rice bowl protection and other forms of office politics. I'm not going to bore with you with all the gory details but I was essentially told to shut up and follow orders. Not much esle to say about it other than I had no choice in the matter.

Comment: I'd want it in writing so when (and not if) the database gets corrupted, I could not be held responsible. And this is also the kind of client I'd "fire." I understand you're likely an employee and can't do that, but you should know that independent consultants would often walk away from such idiocy and leave the client holding the bag.

Comment: That's a good idea. I'll start working on something that I can present to my boss and his boss so that they won't be able to claim that they didn't understand the situation.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing to do is to open a database variable against the backend.  This keeps the lock on the backend LDB file open so Access doesn't waste time working with it.  You might also want to open a recordset variable.

This is particularly important when relinking tables, for example, when you make new front end available to your users which has been pointing to the development database file and which needs to relink to the production database file.  The time spent relinking tables will drop from minutes to seconds.

Also visit my [Access Performance FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/performancefaq.htm) page.

Comment: I currently open a hiidden form that connects to a back end table after the start up checks are run. The form stays iopen as long as the front end is open. If I understand you correctly I should open this form before I start the back end checks. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Yes.   So long as you aren't relinking the tables.  That should be handled separately.